# How to convert String into hashmap

Tags: java

```
String a = "{
 "colmdl":[{"field":"srrno"},
    {"field":"loadport"}],
 "suppressClipboardPaste":true,
 "excelSheetName":"Grid_sheet",
 "editable":true,
 "excelExportType":"Toolbar"
}"
```

this is I stored in as a string , i need to set this as a map.

for ex colmdl,suppressClipboardPaste,excelSheetName,editable, excelExportType these all should be key.

Comment: That looks looks like JSON object. Parse it using some JSON parser and you should get JSONObject which should eliminate need to having a Map (or if not you can easily crate a Map by using key-value pars from that object).

Answer (score 1):

If you still looking for a map, it should be `Map<String,Object>`.
Here is example using ObjectMapper from Jackson library.

```java
String json = "{ ... }"
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(json,new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){})
```

Answer (score 0):

That's JSON data, so you need a JSON reading tool. You need a library to do this. For example, [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson).

Comment: Can u pls give a code